# create polygon on Rshiny leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, polygon

I want to create a map on a shiny app. I use the leaflet package but I don't how I can create many polygons on just one time (more than 15000)
This is a part of my data :

```
ID_Area num LAT1    LONG1   LAT2    LONG2   latitude    longitude   categorie
102584  929 53.34   -6.27   53.35   -6.26   53.345  -6.265  More than 50
102053  549 53.33   -6.26   53.34   -6.25   53.335  -6.255  More than 50
```

So I want to create a grid on a maps with many square and where I can see the "num". I search on the web how can I make this but all tutorial was make with a spatialpolygonsdataframe but i don't understand.

For example I want to have a polygon like that for the first row:

```
a <-53.34,-6.27
b <-53.34,-6.26
c <-53.35,-6.26
d <-53.35,-6.27
poly <- a,b,c,d,NUM,Categorie
```

I'm sorry but I'm a novice on R, it's possible? 
and create a function for the 15000 Rows?
Thanks

Comment: you can try using the `sin` and `cos` to create polygons around a center. But no idea whether you search. I used the sinus-cosinus approach e.g. here: https://github.com/region-spotteR/PrepPlot

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your example code what you want exactly, as the code is not executable like that. Maybe this small example can illustrate you the basics of SpatialObjects in R:

```
library(sp)
Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,2,2),c(2,2,5,5,2)))
Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,12,12,5),c(5,5,12,12)))
Sr3 = Polygon(cbind(c(4,4,5,5,4),c(5,3,3,5,5)))

Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Sr2), "s2")
Srs3 = Polygons(list(Sr3), "s3")
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2,Srs3), 1:3)

SpDf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpP, data=data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3)), match.ID = F)

library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>% 
  addPolygons(data=SpDf, label= as.character(SpDf$ID))
```

You can also check out the answer here, as it might be very similar to your request. ([How to build Quadrants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801813/building-quadrants-in-rshiny/50491145#50491145))

And this is how you would include it in a shinyApp:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addPolygons(data=SpDf, label= as.character(SpDf$ID))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```